# Finding the polynomial

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential, differential-operators

Find a nontrivial polynomial function $p(x)$ such that $p(2x)=p'(x)p''(x)\not=0$

Comment: Aside from $p(x) = 0$?

Comment: @Emisor yes aside from p(x)=0

Answer (score 3):

So you've got $P(x)=Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D$ from @Steven Gregory's post. Then $$\begin{align}8Ax^3+4Bx^2+2Cx+D&=(3Ax^2+2Bx+C)(6AX+2B)\\
&=18A^2x^3+18ABx^2+(4B^2+6AC)x+2BC\end{align}$$ If $A=0$, then we find that $P(x)=0$, so $A=\frac49$, but the $x^2$ term only works if $B=0$, then $C=D=0$ so the polynomial is just $\frac49x^3$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\deg(p(x)) = n$, then we must have

\begin{align}
    deg(p'(x)p''(x)) &= deg(p(2x)) \\
    (n-1) + (n-2) &= n \\
    n &= 3
\end{align}

So let $p(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d\;$ where $\;a \ne 0$:

\begin{align}
    p'(x) p''(x) = p(2x) \\
    18a^2 x^3 + 18ab x^2 + (6ac + 4b^2) x + 2bc
    &= 8a x^3 +   4b x^2 +           2c x +   d \\
    \hline
    18a^2 &= 8a \\
    18ab &= 4b \\
    6ac + 4b^2 &= 2c \\
    2bc &= d \\
    \hline
    a &= \dfrac 49 \\
    b &= 0 \\
    c &= 0 \\
    d &= 0
\end{align}

So $p(x) = \dfrac 49 x^3$

Sorry I got it wrong the first time.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: But the answer can't be just $x^3$

Comment: @user328114 : Haste makes waste.  I've deleted part of my comment. $\qquad$

Comment: @user328114 : And now I've deleted all of it, since Steven Gregory has corrected that particular typo.

Comment: The polynomial does exist and the answer is $(4x^3)/9$ but I don't know how to get the answer

Comment: As semiclassical pointed out, the degree of $p'(x)p''(x)$ is not $n^2 - n + 2$ but $2n - 3$, so $2n - 3 = n \rightarrow n = 3$

Answer (score 1):

Steven Gregory's answer may evolve further in the coming minutes.  Let's try a more concrete approach:
$$
f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d
$$
(Third degree for reasons apparent from Steven Gregory's answer and the accompanying comments.)
\begin{align}
f(2x) & = 8ax^3 + 4bx^2 + 2cx + d \\
f'(x) & = 3ax^2 + 2bx + c \\
f''(x) & = 6ax + 2b \\
f'(x)f''(x) & = 18a^2 x^3 + 18abx^2 + (6ac+4b^2) x + 2bc
\end{align}
Therefore
\begin{align}
8a & = 18 a^2 \\
4b & = 18ab \\
2c & = 6ac+4b^2 \\
d & = 2bc
\end{align}
\begin{align}
a & = \frac 4 9 \\[10pt]
b & = 0 \\[10pt]
c & = 0 \\[10pt]
d & = 0
\end{align}

If $f(x) = \dfrac 4 9 x^3$ then $f(2x) = \dfrac{32} 9 x^3$ and $f'(x) = \dfrac 4 3 x^2 $ and $f''(x) = \dfrac 8 3 x$, $\text{so } f'(x)f''(x) = \dfrac{32} 9 x^3.$

Answer (score 1):

The degrees of each side must match:
$\deg{p(2x)} = \deg\{p'(x) p''(x)\}$

Gives:
$ n = (n-1) + (n-2)$
$ \implies n = 3$

Now we know the degree is 3, try setting $p(x)=a_3 x^3+a_2 x^2 + a_1 x^1+a_0$.
Then evaluate $p(2x)$ and $p'(x) p''(x)$ and equate coefficients.